# Convexe function and mean

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

How do I prove that for convexe functions $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}\colon$

$$ f\Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\Big)\; \leq \;\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)\quad?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_.28finite_form.29

Comment: This is known as Jensen's inequality.  It's a standard property of convex functions that follows almost immediately from most definitions of "convex function."  Your solution to the exercise will depend on the definition that you have.  For example, if your definition of convex function involves convex combinations of two points, then you can use a proof by induction to extend this to n points.

Comment: This is the problem. I don't understand how the "backwards" step (from n to n-1) works and we should use the definition $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

To extend traditional statement about convexity
$$
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y), \forall x,y, \forall \lambda \in [0,1]
$$
into case of $n$ parameters, do the following. Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x_1,x_2,$ and $x_3$ are reals, and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \geq 0$ and sum to $1$. Then,
$$
f(\lambda_1 x_1 +\lambda_2 x_2 +\lambda_3 x_3) = f\left(\lambda_1 x_1 +(1-\lambda_1)\left(\frac{\lambda_2}{1-\lambda_1}x_2 +\frac{\lambda_3}{1-\lambda_1}x_3\right)\right) \\ \leq  \lambda_1f(x_1)+(1-\lambda_1)f\left(\frac{\lambda_2}{1-\lambda_1}x_2 + \frac{\lambda_3}{1-\lambda_1}x_3\right)
\\ \leq \lambda_1 f(x_1) + (1-\lambda_1)\frac{\lambda_2}{1-\lambda_1}f(x_2)+(1-\lambda_1)\frac{\lambda_3}{1-\lambda_1}f(x_3) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_if(x_i).
$$

Now, do this for the case for $n$ parameters (inductively).

**Remark** Lines above uses the fact that $1-\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$ to apply convexity statement twice.

Comment: Thank you very much - I think I will use that as well. (I am not sure which expression we have to use - in the comment above I stated the other definition - and I think the prove is much heavier then).

Comment: If you want to argue via that, I would recommend you to take a look at Exercise 4.24 from Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin; which proves how you can get the actual convexity statement from midpoint convexity. Let me know, if you need to access the solution of that problem.